# Excel - How to assign cell to insert an image

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm creating a template in Excel for something similar to an invoice and would like to enable a certain cell, say B12, to automatically open the file browser (thus allowing me to choose an image I want to insert) when I click said cell.

I was wondering if this was possible and if so, how I would go about doing it.

Thanks in advance.

PS: I'm using the Mac 2011 version of Office.

Comment: It is possible.  I would start by using the macro recorder to show you how to insert an image into the current cell.  Then I would research how to browse for a file in VBA and combine the two processes (browse for the file, use that file in the code that the macro recorder showed you).

Comment: Adding to chancea's excellent suggestions you can the use the `SelectionChange` event to trigger when Selection passes to say `B12`. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following to the code of the worksheet in which you want this image to be inserted.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

On Error GoTo ErrHandler:

    If Not Intersect(Range("B12"), Target) Is Nothing Then
    myPictureName = Application.GetOpenFilename _
    (filefilter:="Picture Files,*.jpg;*.bmp;*.tif;*.gif")
    ActiveSheet.Pictures.Insert(myPictureName).Select
    End If

Exit Sub

ErrHandler:
    Resume Next

End Sub
```